# why while loop function cannot run and print function cannot be run?

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node { 
  int data; 
  struct node *next; 
} NodeT;


NodeT *makeNode(int v);
void joinLL(NodeT *head, int v);
void showLL(NodeT *head);
void freeLL(NodeT *head);
int a;

int main(void){
   
   NodeT *head= NULL;
   bool bo=true;
   while (bo){
      printf("Enter an integer:");
      if (scanf("%d", &a)){
       joinLL(head, a);
       return bo;
     }
       else{
          printf("Done.\n");
           break;
        }
    
   }
  
    showLL(head);
    freeLL(head);

    return 0;
    
}


//creat a new node
NodeT *makeNode(int v) { 
  NodeT *new = malloc(sizeof(NodeT)); 
  assert(new != NULL); 
  new->data = v; // initialise data
  new->next = NULL; // initialise link to next node
  return new; // return pointer to new node
}


//append a new element with data v at the end of list.
void joinLL(NodeT *head, int v){
    NodeT *insert=makeNode(v);
    insert -> next = NULL;  

    if (head==NULL){
        head = insert;  
    }
    else{
        NodeT *temp= head;
        while (temp->next != NULL){
            temp=temp->next;
       }
        temp->next=insert;
    }

 }


    

void showLL(NodeT *head) {

    //iterate the entire linked list and print the data
   NodeT *p;

   for (p = head; p!= NULL; p = p->next) {
        int elements= p->data;
        printf("Done. List is %d-->", elements);
   }
}


void freeLL(NodeT *head) {
   NodeT *p, *temp;

   p = head;
   while (p != NULL) {
      temp = p->next;
      free(p);
      p = temp;
   }
}
```

I have already updated some codes. I would like to the input to be like, asking for input multiple times  and it is going to output the linked list result otherwise, the loop is going to terminate. But the program shows that I can not get multiple inputs and output cannot be shown as well. I'm new in c and do not know how to fix it

Comment: In the function `main`, the statement `return bo;` will cause the program to terminate. I don't think that this is what you want. Does your program work if you delete this line?

Comment: Also, `if (scanf("%d", &a))` is not the correct test. It should be `if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1)`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thanks I have fixed that but why showLL function cannot be printed. If I print a non-numeric value, it only prints done.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why do I need to print like this way?  I hope i can input many numeric values.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: That `if` condition will work as long as `scanf` does not return `EOF`, for example due to the user triggering end-of-file by pressing an OS-specific key combination. I doubt that OP will be doing that, so I believe it should not be a problem. However, you are correct that it is generally better to write it as you suggest.

Comment: @xzha_athena _"why do I need to print like this way?"_ because your current test treats `EOF` as-if `scanf` succeeded in extracting an `int` instead of treating it like it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has at least the following two problems:

1. In the function `main`, the statement `return bo;` will cause the program to terminate. This is not what you want. You should delete this line.
2. You never change the value of the variable `head` of the function `main`, so that it always has the value `NULL`. In particular, changing the variable `head` of the function `joinLL` does not change the value of the variable `head` of the function `main`. Those two variables are distinct, even if they have the same name. What your function `joinLL` is doing is creating a copy of the variable `head` (with the same name) and only changing the value of that copy, instead of changing the value of the original variable.

To fix #2, when calling `joinLL` from `main`, you should pass a pointer to the variable `head` instead of only the value of `head`. That way, you can change the variable `head` of the function `main` from inside the function `joinLL`.

For example, you could rewrite your function `joinLL` like this:

```
//append a new element with data v at the end of list.
void joinLL(NodeT **pp_head, int v) {

    //make pp_next point to the "next" member of the last
    //node of the list, or, if the list is empty, let it
    //continue to point to the variable "head" of the
    //function "main"
    NodeT **pp_next = pp_head;
    while ( *pp_next != NULL )
    {
        pp_next = &(*pp_next)->next;
    }

    //create the new node
    NodeT *insert = makeNode(v);

    //add the new node to linked list
    *pp_next = insert;
}
```

Of course, you would also have to change the forward declaration of the function `joinLL` accordingly. Also, when calling the function `joinLL`, you would have to change the line

```
joinLL(head, a);
```

to:

```
joinLL(&head, a);
```

If you don't want to use pointers to pointers (for example because you find them too complicated), you could also make the function `joinLL` return the address of the new head node, like this:

```
//append a new element with data v at the end of list.
NodeT *joinLL(NodeT *head, int v) {
    NodeT *insert = makeNode(v);

    if (head==NULL){
        return insert;
    }

    NodeT *temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = insert;

    return head;
}
```

In that case, in the function `main`, you would have to change the line

```
joinLL(head, a);
```

to:

```
head = joinLL(head, a);
```

Comment: the coding can be like this? NodeT *point=head; point =joinLL(head, a); @AndreasWenzel

Comment: @xzha_athena: Yes, you could make the function `joinLL` return a pointer to the new head, instead of passing a pointer to the pointer to the head node, as I have done in my posted solution.

Comment: @xzha_athena: I have now added an alternative solution which does not use pointers to pointers, but uses the return value of the function `joinLL` instead.